# Removed Wubi from Add/remove programs menu, but I can still boot into it

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I installed Wubi from a flash drive, then moved it from that into windows (I assume, I can boot without the flash drive now)

I used add/remove programs to uninstall Ubuntu, but I can still boot into it on startup and everything seems to run just fine.

As in similar questions that have been asked, I tried bcedit, but the two entries that showed up were both for Windows.

I'm planning to install either Ubuntu or Mint on it's own partition, but would like to clear out whatever is leftover from Wubi first

Answer (score 0):

If you have attempted to uninstall Wubi but Ubuntu is still there, try "Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe" from the Ubuntu Wiki:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this, but it still has Ubuntu as a boot option